# Stripe Connect with Python Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-connect

I'm trying to set up stripe connect in a Python/Django application so that I can have a number of contractors taking work from a site and being paid directly.

I'm trying to get authorisation by getting a token for a new contractor.  I've got the following view:

```
def authorise(request):
  site = 'https://connect.stripe.com' + '/oauth/authorize'
  params = {
    "response_type": "code",
    "scope": "read_write",
    "client_id": STRIPE_CLIENT_ID
  }

  # Redirect to Stripe /oauth/authorize endpoint
  url = site + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params)
  return redirect(url)
```

This will take me into Stripe to setup a connection but when I select the stripe connect button on the Stripe site I get:

> 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

My callback URL is `127.0.0.1/contractor/stripe_contractor_callback` and the url call is: `http://127.0.0.1/contractor/stripe_contractor_callback?scope=read_write&code=my_text_code`

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I've just noticed it will also not take me to a different page if I just type in a URL which I know if valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the callback.  I need to specify 127.0.0.1:8000 because it is trying to send back to the normal internet port of 80 but I'm running Django development server.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to accept your own answer if it solves your problem

Comment: My bad, didn't check the date :)